# npm unresponsive after nodejs install on fresh Ubuntu 12.04.5

Tags: 12.04, apt, nodejs, npm

Here's where I'm at...

I have an old chromebook that I put Ubuntu (and Xfce) on via crouton. After installing the chromium browser, I installed nodejs via apt-get. I found that when trying to install yeoman, my node version was too old (v0.6).

So, I removed nodejs and npm:

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then followed the instructions here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

After installing nodejs, I can run `nodejs --version` to see the node version is v0.10.36.

Then, when I run `npm --version`, I get no output at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After countless attempts with various approaches, this is what finally worked!

https://gist.github.com/csturtz/11f79e6bd0a05eaca6df

Answer (score 1):

you can install npm using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: Thanks, but nodejs from nodesource includes npm already. There's no longer any reason to install npm separately.

Comment: btw, for precise (12.04LTS) the npm version is 1.1.4.  http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/npm

Answer (score 1):

for me a re-install with the package manager worked. I initially didn't have all security updates installed and after that npm was not available. After installing the updates, a reinstall worked fine.

Comment: Hello Sven, welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you include in the answer  instructions on how to that? Thanks! =)